# questions about the closed graph of topological curve?

Tags: general-topology

Suppose that $M$ is a topological space,$\gamma:dom(\gamma)\rightarrow M$ is continuous,where $dom(\gamma)\subset \mathbb{R}$ is a open interval. Is it possilble that there exists special topological space $M$ satisfying that the graph of $\gamma$ is a closed set in $\mathbb{R}\times M$ for $dom(\gamma)\subsetneqq\mathbb{R}$ (Of course,dom($\gamma$) is still required to be a open interval here)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is certainly possible. For instance, $\gamma(t)=\tan(t)$ (with domain of $\gamma$ equal to $(-\pi/2,\pi/2)$. The graph is the familiar tangent curve and certainly is closed.

In fact, I think more or less the same thing can be done in any arc-connected space which has a topological end, by plotting a curve whose both endpoints go to that end, loosely speaking, and parametrising it using a finite interval.

Comment: Thanks,by the way,what's the meaning of "topological end"?

Answer (score 0):

The graph can not be closed, no matter your choice of $M$.

Consider the image $X$ of $\gamma$ in $\mathbb{R} \times M$, and consider the continuous map $\Gamma : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R} \times M$ given by $t \mapsto (t, \gamma(t))$. Then by the definition of a continuous map, we would have $\Gamma^{-1}(X)$ is closed in $\mathbb{R}$. However, $\Gamma^{-1}(X)$ is nothing but the original domain, which is open. QED.

**Edit:** This isn't quite correct, as it requires you to be able to extend the map $\Gamma$ (which is really only defined on $dom(\gamma)$) to a closed neighbourhood of $dom(\gamma)$. See comments.

Comment: Ah, correct. Fixed.

Comment: In other words,it is possible that the graph of $\gamma$ is closed only for the case dom($\gamma$)=$\mathbb{R}$,yeah?

Comment: $\Gamma$ is not a continuous function from $\mathbb R$; it still has domain $\operatorname{dom} ( \gamma )$ (which is a closed subset of itself).  For example, consider the tangent function $\tan : (\frac{-\pi}2 , \frac \pi 2 ) \to \mathbb{R}$.

Comment: Oh, that's a really good point. Whoops. And it's worth noting that the example you provide gives one case where it does work! Hmm.

Comment: @SimonRose,as you say,$\Gamma^{-1}(X)$ is closed.However,when $\Gamma$ is defined on dom($\gamma$),$\Gamma^{-1}(X)$=dom($\gamma$) actually is a closed set of dom($\gamma$) in the subspace dom($\gamma$).